# Inline JavaScript not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, progress-bar

Is there something wrong with this script? Doesn't seem to work.
CAn someone try this on your end if it works? it works using fiddle but it doesn't work when i run it locally.

```
<HTML>

<HEAD><TITLE>Server Disk Alert</TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../Backup/2012/Web Projects/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.ready(function(){
var widthval = parseInt($('.item').eq(0).text(), 10);
var $hr = $('hr').eq(0);
alert(widthval);
$hr.width(widthval);

if (widthval > 90) {
    $hr.css('background-color', 'red');}

});

</script>

</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="#EFEFFF">


<TABLE id="table_id" BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="2" CELLSPACING="2">
<TR>
 <TH COLSPAN="5" ALIGN="CENTER">Critical Server Disk Space</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
 <TH>Server</TH>
 <TH>Drive</TH>
 <TH>Percent Free Space</TH>
 <TH>Size Free Space</TH>
 <TH>Status</TH>
</TR>


<TR>
 <TD>%server%</TD>
 <TD>%drive%</TD>
 <TD class="item">50%</TD>
 <TD>%fspace%</TD>
 <TD width=200 style="border: 2px solid silver;padding:none">
 <hr style="color:#c00;background-color:blue;height:15px; border:none; margin:0;" align="left"/> </TD>
</TR>
<TR>

</TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here's the jsfiddle link which what I'm trying to accomplish.  
http://jsfiddle.net/XhxkX/7/

Comment: Lots of flaws, you are loading 2 different versions of jQuery, secondly your jQuery selectors syntax can be used in a better way. Use $("hr") instead of $(document).get.....

Comment: Thanks. please show me how the code should look like. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it! Thanks to an old friend who walked me through it.. here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Critical Server Disk Space</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.bar').each(function(i){

                    var width = parseInt($('.item').eq(i).text(), 10);
                    var hr = $(this).eq(i);

                    $(this).width(width);

                    if(width >= 90){
                        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
                    }
                });

            });

            //window.onload = init();
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            hr{
                border:none;
                background:blue;
                height:15px;
                margin:0px;     
                text-align:left;
            }
            .border{border:1px solid #CCC; padding:0px; width:100px;background:#FFF;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#EFEFFF" >
        <TABLE BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="2" CELLSPACING="2">
            <TR>
             <TH COLSPAN="5" ALIGN="CENTER">Critical Server Disk Space</TH>
            </TR>
            <TR>
             <TH>Server</TH>
             <TH>Drive</TH>
             <TH>Percent Free Space</TH>
             <TH>Size Free Space</TH>
             <TH>Status</TH>
            </TR>
            <TR>
             <TD>%server%</TD>
             <TD>%drive%</TD>
             <TD class="item">50 <!-- 2% --></TD>
             <TD>%fspace%</TD>
             <TD width=200">
              <div class="border"><hr class="bar" /></div>
             </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
             <TD>%server%</TD>
             <TD>%drive%</TD>
             <TD class="item">30 <!-- 2% --></TD>
             <TD>%fspace%</TD>
             <TD width=200">
              <div class="border"><hr class="bar" /></div>
             </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
             <TD>%server%</TD>
             <TD>%drive%</TD>
             <TD class="item">95 <!-- 2% --></TD>
             <TD>%fspace%</TD>
             <TD width=200">
              <div class="border"><hr class="bar" /></div>
             </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
             <TD>%server%</TD>
             <TD>%drive%</TD>
             <TD class="item">80 <!-- 2% --></TD>
             <TD>%fspace%</TD>
             <TD width=200">
              <div class="border"><hr class="bar" /></div>
             </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't working because you're mixing regular JavaScript DOM methods with jQuery.

This should work a little better:

```
var width = parseInt($('.item').eq(0).text(), 10);
var $hr = $('hr').eq(0);

$hr.width(width);

if (width > 90) {
    $hr.css('background-color', 'red');
}​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XhxkX/10/**

Also, there are a few invalid tags in your HTML (`<LPFOOTER>` and `<LPHEADER>`). I'm not sure what they're for, but they are both improperly placed and one of them is missing an opening tag. I suggest you update your HTML to current standards before working much more with it.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your code and replaced my previous code. but still it doesn't work when i compile it on the actual page. but it works on jsfiddle.  <BR/>
Did i miss something?

Comment: Probably. There must be something else in your HTML page.

Comment: the html body is exactly the same as what is posted on the jsfiddle link. I just copied and pasted it there.

Comment: Hi @Blender  this is actually a template for logparser. these can be safely ignored. even if i take these tags off, i still get the same error. :/

Comment: I appreciate all your answers, i know each of these are correct. I just can't figure out what's wrong with my code. any other suggestions, guys?

Comment: it's not actually an error. it just doesn't display the bar correctly. If i place a value on the `<td>` field, the bar doesn't change and remains at 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).getElementsByTagName("hr")[0].style.width = widthValue;​`

Should be:

`document.getElementsByTagName("hr")[0].style.width = widthValue;​`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<HEAD><TITLE>Server Disk Alert</TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../Backup/2012/Web Projects/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var widthValue = document.getElementsByClassName("item")[0].innerText;
document.getElementsByTagName("hr")[0].style.width = widthValue;​

if (parseInt(widthValue, 10) > 90) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("hr")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
​
});
</script>
</HEAD>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mixing `javascript` and `jquery`

use this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var widthValue = $(".item").text();
$("hr").css("width",widthValue)
if (parseInt(widthValue, 10) > 90) {
   $("hr").css("backgroundColor","red");
}
​
});
```

Comment: Missing closing paran on your second css() function.

Answer (score 0):

that should work I used to different approaches to show how you can access and manipulative the DOM elements. I hope that helps.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var widthValue = parseInt($('.item').eq(0).text());
$('hr').eq(0).css('width',widthValue) ;

if (parseInt((widthValue.replace('%','')/10)* 10) > 90) {
   $('hr').eq(0).css({'background-color':'red'});
}

});
```

​​

Comment: Hi, for some reason I'm still getting negative output. :/ something's gotta be wrong somewhere.

Comment: figured my fault overlooked some areas

Comment: Hi, this only increases the width of the item td. i need to retain the % value of the td.

Comment: ok i hoping thats it. now you cant utilize  the % symbol is consider a modulus symbol we from my understanding cant use it so you have to break it down. i have done soand have tested in fiddle@ 91% color change was enabled

Comment: actually the code i provided above already works in fiddle. only thing is that if i use it on my page it won't work. the bar just remains in 100% width it doesn't conform with the referenced widthValue

Comment: one thing did come to mind as i look back at the top of the page ... why to jquery libs?

Comment: yah, that's one thing. would you know which one should i use?

Comment: i would use a local version and make sure it's updated and unmodified

Comment: i posted the actual code i have on my page. can you try it on your end if it works?  thanks.. :)